# Jquery invoke $.when after a function finished

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
isPublisher.done(function(isActive) {
    if (isActive) {
        AddRoleToUser(inlineUid, "Publisher");
    }
    $.when(SetCountryAndLanguage(), GetUserRoles()).done(SetInlineManualTracking);
});

//Add Role to inline manual table in DB.
function AddRoleToUser(userId, role) {
   return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Publisher/Service.asmx/AddRoleToUser",
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: userId, role: role }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

I want the `$.when` to occur only after `AddRoleToUser` function finished. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What is the code in `AddRoleToUser()`? Presumably it's an AJAX request, otherwise the code would already be doing what you require

Comment: Hi Rory, @RoryMcCrossan, it's an ajax request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want the `$.when` to occur only after `AddRoleToUser` function finished.

That's what your current code does. But assuming `AddRoleToUser` starts an asynchronous process, and you want to wait until that process completes, `AddRoleToUser` will need to accept a callback or return a promise.

If we assume it returns a promise, then you can have your call to `$.when` wait for that to resolve (using a dummy promise instead if you don't call it):

```
isPublisher.done(function(isActive) {
    var p;
    if (isActive) {
        p = AddRoleToUser(inlineUid, "Publisher");
    } else {
        p = $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
    }
    p.then(function() {
        $.when(SetCountryAndLanguage(), GetUserRoles()).done(SetInlineManualTracking);
    });
});
```

Comment: AddRoleToUser is an ajax request, I added it in my question.

Comment: @OffirPe'er So `AddRoleToUser()` should return the ajax request (promise): `function AddRoleToUser(userId, role) { return $.ajax(...); }`  EDIT: now following your opening question edit, i'm not really sure what you are using as code or not...?!

Comment: @A.Wolff I added it.

Comment: @OffirPe'er: Since you're returning the `jqXHR` object, which is a *thenable* (something that's promise-like), the above will work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it works now like I wanted and thank you for that.
Can you explain/referrer me what p = $.Deferred().resolve().promise(); does exactly in simple words? I read about it in many places but it was difficult for me to understand since English is not my mother language.

Comment: @OffirPe'er: `$.Deferred()` returns a jQuery `$.Deferred` object. Calling `resolve()` on it resolves it; `resolve` returns the `$.Deferred` you call it on. Calling `promise()` on it gives you a jQuery `$.Promise` object. (You could actually just call `then` on the `$.Deferred`, so we could have left out the `promise()` bit.) Since the `$.Deferred` is resolved, calling `then` on it runs the callback immediately. (With up-to-date jQuery, it runs it immediately but asynchronously; with older jQuery, it runs it synchronously.)

Comment: Can I say that "AddRoleToUser" function is a jQuery $.Deferred object?@T.J.Crowder

Comment: @OffirPe'er: No. It *returns* a `jqXHR` object, which is promise-like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118546/discussion-between-offir-peer-and-t-j-crowder).